# error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurescript, cider

attempting to start `cider` with M-x `cider-jack-in` with clojure project file in current buffer on Emacs 24.4.1. I get `error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server`

does nREPL need separate installation...is this an error anyone else is experiencing with 24.4.1?

messages buffer:
`Starting nREPL server via /usr/bin/lein update-in :dependencies conj \[org.clojure/tools.nre\
                         |11:56:07 hello:                                                                              |pl\ \"0.2.12\"\] -- update-in :plugins conj \[cider/cider-nrepl\ \"0.14.0-SNAPSHOT\"\] -- re\
                         |11:56:07 hello:                                                                              |pl :headless...
                         |11:56:08 hello:                                                                              |error in process sentinel: nrepl-server-sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: ^[[?25h^[[0G\`

Comment: What version of CIDER do you use? Can you show your `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: cider version: ```20160122.440``` @OlegTheCat

Comment: I meant version that is obtained via `M-x cider-version <RET>`. Can you show that? Also it seems to be issue in your project (however, I don't see any exceptions in `*Messages*` buffer, strange ...). Does launching REPL from console work, e.g. `lein repl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple matter of having the correct versions of lein and clojure(script) and rtfm on https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider-nrepl. To solve this I had to upgrade clojure to `1.7+` and lein to `2.5.2`. After these upgrades everything worked nicely.